# Adjust Sheets formula by +1 row -- ('SheetX'!$A3) in column A --> ('SheetX'!$A4) in column B

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

**PSA: We're doing this to create grocery lists for people in need**

I am trying to create a list from Google Form submissions. 
I re-ordered the list in a new tab, so each 'form' row will be displayed as a column.

I've mapped Row 2 from the original form to **column B** in the new sheet. The formulas in column B look like this:

```
=('Requests (form)'!$U$2)
=('Requests (form)'!$BA$2)
=('Requests (form)'!$T$2)
=('Requests (form)'!$R$2)
```

In the next column (column C) I want to map Row 3.
It should look like this:

```
=('Requests (form)'!$U$3)
=('Requests (form)'!$BA$3)
=('Requests (form)'!$T$3)
=('Requests (form)'!$R$3)
```

If I remove the "$" it does not help, since it will still return the next COLUMN rather than the next row.

For example:  ('SheetX'!$A3) in column A to to ('SheetX'!$A4) in column B

```
What I want: BA3 --> BA4 
NOT what I want: BA3 --> BB3
```

THERE must be a macro or something that can do something so simple.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `Transpose()`? For example `transpose('Requests (form)'!$U$2:U20)`

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: Here's an example of a sheet.  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D5FuL92fcZgMkM_VXUIzoE6JjAM-jah2ncqtYzG-xN4/edit#gid=647101176.

Comment: I added a Transpose() example to the example worksheet you sent. Is this not a good solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You need to

- chose the columns of interest in the correct oder (can be done with a `select` [query](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en))
- [Transpose](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094262?hl=en) the results

Sample formula:

```
=TRANSPOSE(Query(Requests (form)!A1:BA, "select U, BA, T,R"))
```